# Not able to disable past dates on vuejs-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

I want to disable all past dates before "today". I am using vuejs-datepicker. [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker) However it's not working nor there are any errors in the console log. I can still choose past dates.

```
<datepicker
     v-model="date"
     :format="DatePickerFormat"
     :disabledDates="disabledDates">
</datepicker>

data(){
      return {
        date: '',
        DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        disabledDates: {
          to: new Date(Date.now() - 8640000)
        }
      }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

***Update1:***

```
<template>
  <datepicker
     v-model="model.date"
     :format="DatePickerFormat"
     :disabledDates="disabledDates">
</datepicker>
</template>

<script>
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'

  export default {

    components: {
      Datepicker
    },

    data(){
      return {
        model: {
          date: ''
        }
        DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        disabledDates: {
          to: new Date(Date.now() - 8640000)
        }
      }
    }

  }

</script>
```

[image]

I still can choose past dates before 19.07.2018

Comment: Can you prepare a short example showing the problem? Works fine in my case.

Comment: Yeah sure, but prepare where? Because the above code is from the project in which I am trying to solve this. I updated my first post with copy-paste of .vue file.

Comment: Use `codesandbox.io` (like it [datepicker demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mpklq49wp)) or any other Vue-supporting online tool. As it stands, it's not clear what goes wrong in your case; the code by itself looks fine to me.

Comment: It's the same as @puelo gave in the answer in codesandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a "," in your data object:

```
data() {
      return {
        model: {
          date: ''
        }, <---------------------------
        DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        disabledDates: {
          to: new Date(Date.now() - 8640000)
        }
      }
    }
```

Other than that it seems to be working for me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ww60k220z8

**Edit:** Turns out you used an outdated version of vuejs-datepicker which was build for VueJS 1.x. For problems in the future it might be beneficial to also post your package.json ;)

Comment: Nope, totally clean ... Hell that's strange ... No clue of what's happening.

Comment: Which version of vuejs-datepicker are you using?

Comment: Well the newest, I installed through "npm install vuejs-datepicker --save". Imported it in the .vue file and ... as it's in the documentation. The missing "," was a typo

Comment: Then u might have to debug your problem. If you serve through webpack or something similar you should be able to set breakpoints inside the Datepicker components and then maybe find out what is wrong. You maybe could also remove parts of your app until you find what is causing the issue. It is hard to tell what is going on, but seems to be an isolated issue with your application

Comment: I stripped everything from the .vue file that wasn't connected with the datepicker - again it doesn't work, what the hell is happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176329/discussion-between-puelo-and-decrux).

Comment: to me also it gives console error: TypeError: disabledDates() expects an array parameter. It means I have to provide the array of past dates like this :  disabledDates: [ ]

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `v-date-picker`, from Vuetify, just set the props `min`

```
              <v-date-picker
                      v-model="dateTermino"
                      :min="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
              ></v-date-picker>
```

Comment: It works even without the `.substr(0, 10)` part.

Comment: Can you please explain what 10 represents in you answer's code? Does that represent days? months? Thanks

Comment: @Ken on my test, Date().toISOString() was returning a datetime in a format different from the desired. and the substr was used to get only the first 10 characters of it, which would result in the expected format

Answer (score 4):

Disabled date has only worked for me when I inform some value for **open-date** property, as follow:

```html
<template>
  <datepicker
     v-model="model.date"
     :format="DatePickerFormat"
     :open-date="new Date()"
     :disabledDates="disabledDates">
  </datepicker>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you using v-calendar

you just neet to add this property "min-date"

This is an example.

```
<v-date-picker
  v-model='date'
  :min-date='new Date()'
  is-inline
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Came here because of the problem but after checking my console I saw the issue.

`<datepicker :input-class="'form-control bg-light'" :disabled-dates="state.dateDisabled"></datepicker>`

use 
`:disabled-dates="state.dateDisabled"`

instead of 
`:disabledDates="state.dateDisabled"`

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: I had this exact same problem. Renaming to disabled-dates helped.