# How can I disable weekend days from an input type = date in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to disable weekend days from a `type = "data"` in `Vue.js`.

```
<input
v-model="selDate"
type="date"
:min= today/>
```

Comment: Try date picker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420756/not-able-to-disable-past-dates-on-vuejs-datepicker